# MS Teams: show background effects option not available

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-teams

I've installed the latest version of MS Teams, but I can't see the Show Background Effects option. Any clues on why that option is not available on my app? I'm using version 1.3.00.9267.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Background effects in Teams enables users to blur their video background or replace their video background with a Microsoft-provided or custom image in meetings where the user has their video turned on. Background effects is supported in scheduled meetings, instant channel meetings, and Teams to Teams video calls. Starting in May, users will be able to upload custom background images using the Teams client.

According to [Change your background for a Teams meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780), if you don't see Show background effects as an option in the menu, the feature might not be available on your device yet.

For now, Linux users aren't able to use this feature.

Background effects won't be available to you if you're using Teams through virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI).

Background effects requires a processor with Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2) support. See [Hardware decoder and encoder driver recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/hardware-decoders-and-encoders)  for a list of unsupported decoders and encoders.

PS: I have Microsoft Teams Version 1.3.00.10058 (64-bit). It was last updated on 4/24/2020.

Answer (score 1):

As Herb said, it's only during the call that you may blur or set the background image, provided that the other technical requirements are met (sufficient OS, version and hardware).

Below are some screenshots for Microsoft Teams for Windows to clarify where the options are (version 1.3.00.21759 64 bits last updated on 8/20/20).

Teams menu while calling:

[image: Teams menu while calling]

Teams background settings, default is to not apply a background image, it's also possible to select blur here:

[image: Teams background settings, default is to not apply a background image, it's also possible to select blur here]

Teams error while uploading an image during the call:

[image: Teams error while uploading an image during the call]